# Problem with choice of distribution and right stat test

Tags: python, statistics, scipy.stats, statistical-test

I have specific data about troubles on a plant. To analyze it, I decided to use `fitter` and find best distribution that fits my data. After using `kstest` for the best fit, I saw this strange result:

```python
KstestResult(statistic=0.9866071428571429, pvalue=0.0)
```

I can't understand why it is happening and want to hear better solutions for this case.

The code I used is shared below:

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats as stats
from fitter import Fitter

with open('310510_sum.txt', 'r') as f: 
    text = f.read()
    
text = text.replace(',','.')
datat = [ float(x) for x in text.split('\n') ]
datat.sort()


f = Fitter(datat,
           distributions=['alpha',
                          'beta',
                          'burr',
                          'lognorm',
                          'genpareto'])

f.fit()
f.get_best(method = 'sumsquare_error')


x = np.linspace(0,100,1000_000)

scipy.stats.kstest(datat, stats.alpha.cdf(x, *params))
```

You can use this data below to run the code.

```
48,0.1,12,16,8,8,24,6,6,3,2,1,6,3,4,8,4,4,6,4,8,8,182,3,4,18,8,6,16,0.3,0.2,4,72,2,64,2,6,8,6,14,6,8,16,2,8,20,5,6,7,4,5,120,64,16,8,8,4,16,10,8,6,7,8,8,14,1,1.6,96,16,8,22,27,7,16,6,32,40,62,8,12,42,9,18,139,64,64,120,8,46,212,1.5,72,142,10,5,60,12,30,8,16,24,24,32,6,4,6,9,6,62,8,8,18,64,1,32,8,8,6,8,142,48,6,8,13,32,8,6,4,8,8,6.4,64,128,20,8,5,7.4,5,11,38,25,8,54,20,4,6,8,8,4,8,56,96,8,8,60,24,3,2,1.3,6,10,16,18,18,96,40,24,8,4,20,19,96,152,8,2,8,13,12,74,4,8,1,6,12,8,4,80,10,6,6,38,5,6,8,8,8,12,8,5.1,4,140,16,8,80,36,8,6,6,8,10,16,16,12,2,8,108,14,22,4,8,6,4,5,13
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When the data is 'the output' produced as a result of some mathematical relations in the background, it can show leptokurtoic properties as in your example. So you first need to model the data, then, with right model that conforms the theory behind it, the residuals of your model is supposed be distributed in one of the usual forms.

In short, your data needs a good model that fits, not a good distribution.